# Jenkins parameters with powershell

Tags: powershell, jenkins

how to pass the jenkins string parameters to power shell script param value?

I have to pass the source path url to the powershell script param value.
Given the Source path as string parameter in jenkins. I want to know how to pass the jenkins parameter value into powershell script param value.

Comment: Can you be more specific or give an example of what you're trying? Check to see if this will help you - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/PowerShell+Plugin

Comment: It's an old question but maybe an article like this helps:
https://blog.inedo.com/jenkins/run-parameterized-ps-scripts/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Every parameter in a job is available to PowerShell as an environment variable, so if your parameter is named i.e. `SourcePath` you can write it in PowerShell as `${env:SourcePath}`

Comment: $env:SourcePath also can be used